# If statement inside a While loop

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I have looked at some examples but don't seen to be able to find what I am looking for.

I need to make the cells in a table change colour if the amount in quantity is less than the threshold.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE type='hardware' ORDER BY item ASC");

echo "<table border='1' align='center' width='600'>
<tr>
<th align='left' bgcolor='#00a3e0'><font face='Arial'>Hardware Stock Item</font></th>
<th bgcolor='#00a3e0'><font face='Arial'>Quantity</font></th>
<th bgcolor='#00a3e0'><font face='Arial'>Location</font></th>
</tr>";

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><font face='Arial'>" . $row1['item'] . "</font></td>";

if ($row1['quantity'] => $row1['threshold']) {
echo "<td align='center'><font face='Arial'>" . $row1['quantity'] . "</font></td>";
} else {
echo "<td align='center' bgcolor='red'><font face='Arial'>" . $row1['quantity'] . "</font></td>";
}

echo "<td align='center'><font face='Arial'>" . $row1['location'] . "</font></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Did you mean `>=`?

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: Also, please do *not* abuse the snippet tools. That is for HTML/CSS/Javascript *only*.

Comment: your if has wrong syntax

Comment: Implement a Counter and if the Value is higher than the Counter, set the Color

Comment: `=>` is not a valid if operator use `>=` instead

Comment: if ($row1['quantity'] >= $row1['threshold']) {.... operator is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not describe what exact issue you were having, but for one thing, this line :

```
if ($row1['quantity'] => $row1['threshold']) {
```

is wrong.

Maybe you made a typo error that went unnoticed, anyway there is a syntax error and the correctly written operator does the opposite of what you expect :

`=>` isn't a comparison operator, it's an assignation operator when assigning array values, the correct comparison operator is `>=`.

Besides, `>=` is the *lte* operator, in other words it means *larger than or equal*.
Since you apparently intend to change the element's colour when the quantity is lesser than the threshold, you should use the *lesser than* operator which is `<` :

```
if ($row1['quantity'] < $row1['threshold']) {
```

If however the mistake is in your explanaition and you planned to include equlaty in your condition, then you should go for the *lesser than or equal* operator, which is `<=` :

```
if ($row1['quantity'] <= $row1['threshold']) {
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is working but `else` part runs 2 times.

If my condition is `wrong` then it displays `Invalid Email & Password` single time but it runs multiple time. Why?

```
    <?php
    require_once('connection.php');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass_wrd = $_POST['pass'];
    
        $qry = "SELECT email,pswd FROM registration ";
        $fetchdata = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    
        while ($arraydata = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchdata)) {
            if (($email == $arraydata['email']) && ($pass_wrd == $arraydata['pswd'])) {
                echo '<script>alert("Data Submitted")</script>';
            } else {
                echo "not";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```